# how to change the sku id in search un url not do be come?

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, phtml, magento-2.1.9

how to change the url key in sku id not be  come?

[image]

how to remove product name to add the sku id?

pls help me?

Comment: You need to change url key as per your requirement right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto  Admin Panel and search the sku id edit the products details in (search engine optimizations) change the custom url keys

[image]

Finally,

php bin/magento setup:di:compile.

php bin/magento indexer:reindex.

and give me permission .

Its Working :)